# MySQL Table of Active Users

Tags: php, mysql, session, authentication

I know that I can reference `$_SESSION` table to set and get temporary data of the currently authenticated user. However, for security reasons, only the computer requesting a page can be given values linked to their browser session cookie. I could update a table for logins each time users log in or log out, but this will not account for people who close their browser or go inactive for a while. How else could I approach this?

This is not like the duplicate someone attached. I am wanting to use the table of active users so that users on a webpage will know if their friends are online.

Comment: @Quentin - Please remove duplicate so others can answer or explain how the different question that you linked this to answers my question.

Comment: If you would like your question to be reopened, you will need to compel the reopen-voters by improving your question.  Show us what code you are currently using.  Show us how you attempted to self-solve.  Show us what pages on SO you found (while searching and researching) that have been nearly right.  Ensure that your question is neither unclear, nor too broad.  I found this question in the Reopen Queue as others will.  Please do everything in your power to make this page irresistible to reopen.